# Setting Flag on Click Event for Candlestick Chart

Tags: highcharts

I found this thread here, but it didn't help me, so I ask again.
[HighStock HighCharts Setting Flag on Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783549/highstock-highcharts-setting-flag-on-click-event)

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/KDP87/10/

I have two questions:

1. How can I get the ohlc-values in the click event function? I tried this.points[0].point.close, which works in the tooltip formatter function, but not when clicking.
2. How can I set a flag on a candle in the way like http://jsfiddle.net/U2Z2x/2/ does?

   ```
       plotOptions: {
           series: {
               cursor: 'pointer',
               point: {
                   events: {
                       click: function () {
                           alert('Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.x) + ', value: ' + this.y);
                           alert('Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.x) + ', close: ' + this.points[0].point.close);                         
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       },
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open / close / high / low values are available in `this` object.

```
alert('Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.x) +  'value: ' + this.y + ', close: ' + this.close + ' open: ' + this.open + ' high: ' + this.high + ' low: ' + this.low);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDP87/13/

2) You need to add flag series.

http://jsfiddle.net/KDP87/14/